# Sort objects in a List based on String labels

Tags: java

I have a list of objects that I am implementing a custom Comparator to sort them into the format as desired by me.

My object looks like the following

```
storageZoneId = <a long value>
floorNo = <an integer>
status = <CREATED/DRAFT>
```

I want my list of objects to be sorted such that they are ordered first by all DRAFT status, then by StorageZoneId and then by floorNo. What I have implemented till now does the final two steps, but how can I do the first one - basically split the list such that all "DRAFT" status are first followed by all "CREATED".

```
public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        ServiceRequest serviceRequest1 = (ServiceRequest) o1;
        ServiceRequest serviceRequest2 = (ServiceRequest) o2;
        int compare_zone = Long.compare(serviceRequest1.getStorageZoneId(), serviceRequest2.getStorageZoneId());
        if (compare_zone == 0) {
            return Integer.compare(serviceRequest1.getFloorNumer(), serviceRequest2.getFloorNumer());
        } else {
            return compare_zone;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem with that? Just compare the two status and return 0 if both are the same or -1/1 if left/right is DRAFT (and thus the other isn't).

Comment: If you get more status in the future which you want to order you might want to switch logic a little and assign each status a numeric value (e.g. by using an enum with either ordinal or a property or doing a lookup in a map) and compare those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Java 8+ you could create your comparator in another way:

```
//put this somewhere so you don't recreate it everytime
Map<String, Integer> statusOrder = new HashMap<>();
statusOrder.put("DRAFT", 1);
statusOrder.put("CREATED", 2);  

Comparator<ServiceRequest> comp = Comparator.comparing(sr -> statusOrder.get(sr.getStatus()))
                                    .thenComparing(ServiceRequest::getStorageZoneId)
                                    .thenComparing(ServiceRequest::getFloorNumer);
```

(Note: the syntax might contain error since I wrote this off the top of my head without having access to a compiler atm)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that something like so should do the trick:

```
public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        ServiceRequest serviceRequest1 = (ServiceRequest) o1;
        ServiceRequest serviceRequest2 = (ServiceRequest) o2;

        if (o1.getStatus().equals("DRAFT") && o2.getStatus().equals("CREATED")){
            return 1;
        }
        if (o1.getStatus().equals("CREATED") && o1.getStatus().equals("DRAFT")){
            return -1;
        }

        int compare_zone = Long.compare(serviceRequest1.getStorageZoneId(), serviceRequest2.getStorageZoneId());
        if (compare_zone == 0) {
            return Integer.compare(serviceRequest1.getFloorNumer(), serviceRequest2.getFloorNumer());
        } else {
            return compare_zone;
        }
    }
```

If the status of `o1` is "DRAFT" and status of `o2` is "CREATED" then `o1` comes first for sure - return 1. In the second comparison the situation is reversed. Only if status of both is the same then other fields matter, we just continue with what you got so far.

Answer (score 1):

```
enum Status {
    DRAFT,
    CREATED
}

class MyObject {
    long storageZoneId;
    int floorNo;
    Status status;

    public MyObject(long storageZoneId, int floorNo, Status status) {
        this.storageZoneId = storageZoneId;
        this.floorNo = floorNo;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public long getStorageZoneId() {
        return storageZoneId;
    }

    public int getFloorNo() {
        return floorNo;
    }

    public Status getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyObject{" +
                "storageZoneId=" + storageZoneId +
                ", floorNo=" + floorNo +
                ", status=" + status +
                '}';
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<MyObject> myObjectList = new ArrayList<>();
        myObjectList.add(new MyObject(1, 5, Status.DRAFT));
        myObjectList.add(new MyObject(3, 2, Status.DRAFT));
        myObjectList.add(new MyObject(4, 3, Status.CREATED));
        myObjectList.add(new MyObject(6, 8, Status.CREATED));

        Comparator<MyObject> comparator = Comparator.comparing(MyObject::getStatus)
                .thenComparing(MyObject::getStorageZoneId)
                .thenComparing(MyObject::getFloorNo);

        myObjectList.sort(comparator);

        for (MyObject obj : myObjectList) {
            System.out.println(obj);
        }
    }
```

Just to add to the other answer, you can use the Comparator builder to simplify the Comparator logic. The status field is defined as an enum, and enums are sorted based on the relative ordering in which the enum values appear in the enum definition. So your list will first be sorted based on DRAFT status as it appears first in the enum, and then CREATED status.